# What kind of yucca is this?

Tags: identification

I bought it online. It said "silver yucca" but i doubt that's its actual name. It also said that it would grow 2 to 3 feet in height. The one i have here is spinless. The ends, though appear sharp but they actually quiet soft to the touch. [image][image]